# Switching fullscreen in java and behaviour of dispose() when only having one window

Tags: java, awt

This question is about the dispose() method in java.
I'm trying to implement a window class, in which I want to be able to switch between fullscreen exclusive mode and a normal window mode.
According to the implementation of this [this site](http://gpsnippets.blogspot.de/2007/08/toggle-fullscreen-mode.html) you can dispose() a frame and reuse it again. But according to the [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) this could result in the VM terminating (as it is the only window I will use).

Is the implementation according to the website simply a bad idea or am I misunderstanding something about the behaviour of dispose()?

The code from the website:

```
//set the display mode back to the what it was when
//the program was launched.
device.setDisplayMode(dispModeOld);

//hide the frame so we can change it.
setVisible(false);

//remove the frame from being displayable.
dispose();

//put the borders back on the frame.
setUndecorated(false);

//needed to unset this window as the fullscreen window.
device.setFullScreenWindow(null);

//make sure the size of the window is correct.
setSize(800,600);

//recenter window
setLocationRelativeTo(null);

//reset the display mode to what it was before
//we changed it.
setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a look around especially the page on how to [ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that you questions has good chances of being answered instead of being down voted or closed. Most important are code examples.

Comment: Set the [`defaultCloseOperation `](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation-int-) to something like `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`.  I would test to see if you really need to call `dispose` in between `setFullScreenWindow` calls

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tested if the dispose call is needed to use the setUndecorated method, and it unfortunately is.

Comment: Okay, so my second thought would be to have two different frames, one for full screen, one for normal and utilise some kind of component (like a `JPanel`) and the basic view and simply move it between the windows